# Converting a Boolean to a string within a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
 list = ['MANAGEMENT (1) (Distributor)',False,'Worker(1) (Distributor)',]
```

I need to remove the boolean and change it to a string

```
 list = ['MANAGEMENT (1) (Distributor)','False','Worker(1) (Distributor)',]
```

I have tied to use (str) but this does not work. I have a feeling I need to use list comprehension but I am not sure how to set that up.

Comment: I would avoid using `list` as a variable name, since it is a reserved word

Comment: How is it that `str` "does not work"?  It works fine for me.  You didn't post your failing attempt, so we can't diagnose that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list comprehension would definitely be a way to solve this, by applying `str` to all the items in it:

```py
lst = [str(i) for i in lst]
```